# A question on Schur's lemma and semisimple modules

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

One variant of Schur's Lemma states that 
$$
\text{Hom}(S,T) \cong \left\{ \begin{matrix} 0 & \text{if } S \neq T \\  \mathbb{C} & \text{if } S = T \end{matrix}  \right.
$$
when $S,T$ are simple modules over a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $A$.

I would like a similar result for $\text{Hom}(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n S_i,S)$. Will it be isomorphic to $ \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \text{Hom}(S_i,S) $ or is this just wishful thinking?

EDIT: and the same question for $ \text{Hom}(\bigoplus S_i,\bigoplus T_j) $

EDIT 2: OK i know where i was confused, for some reason i thought $\text{Hom}(U,V)$ was an algebra when it's actually a module

Comment: For your deleted question: $\Bbb C\oplus\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb C[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)$ are nonisomorphic two-dimensional $\Bbb C$-algebras. | Yes $\hom$ distributes over (*arbitrary*) direct sums in both arguments. In fact there is a *canonical* isomorphism. Can you tell what it is?

Comment: I'm good now, thanks for all the help!

Comment: @JC574 For your deleted question (I think you should undelete it), the answer is yes if the algebras are commutative *and* semisimple.

Comment: @egreg If I get time later tonight I'll reask it and tag you. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S, S_i, T, T_i$ are simple modules, then
$$
\dim\text{Hom}(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n S_i,S) = \sum_{i=1}^n \dim \text{Hom} (S_i, S).
$$
is the number of $S_i$ isomorphic to $S$.

For
$$
\dim \text{Hom}(\bigoplus S_i,\bigoplus T_j)
$$
you get the "same thing".

Comment: so we have dimensions, but no algebra isomorphism necessarily?

Comment: @JC574: Sorry, yes, we have isomorphisms. I just tend to think in terms of dimensions. You just get copies of $\mathbb{C}$.